# Characters for ASCII print of table

Tags: java, formatting, character, ascii-art

I created a small utility to print tables in Java which outputs stuff like:

```
/-----------\
|  header   |
⊢---⊤---⊤---⊣
| A | B | C |
⊢---⊥-⊤-⊥---⊣
| D   | E   |
⊢---⊤-⊥-⊤---⊣
| A | B | C |
∟---⊥---⊥---/
```

Which is pretty ugly because the lines of the different characters are not aligned, currently I fall back on the `+` char to have:

```
⋅-----------⋅
|  header   |
+---+---+---+
| A | B | C |
+---+-+-+---+
| D   | E   |
+---+-+-+---+
| A | B | C |
⋅---+---+---⋅
```

But I was wondering if this was possible to have cleaner symbols like the `T` and `L` but centered in order to join the `-` and `|`.

This is Java code so I can easily use any `UTF-8` char but did not find anything that suited me in the math character tables. If these characters exist only in other encoding I'm also interested I can find a way to use them.

Comment: Try to use UTF8 "Box Drawing" block U+2500 ("\u2500") - U+256C http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2500.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to valexhome, the UTF8 block "Box Drawing" was indeed was I was looking for, now its wonderful :

```
┌───────────┐
│  header   │
├───┬───┬───┤
│ A │ B │ C │
├───┴─┬─┴───┤
│ D   │ E   │
├───┬─┴─┬───┤
│ A │ B │ C │
└───┴───┴───┘
```

Comment: missing `┼` for the perfect exemple